# Call a python function using HTML/Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, websocket, channel

I have a camera Speed Dome Intelbras VIP 5220 SD IR that I can move its position (PTZ function) using python code. However, I want to move its position using a button on the Webpage. I create a webpage using Django, so I want to click on the button and I want my camera to move after that, but I do not know how to call my python function using Django. I found some keywords like Django Channels, Ajax and WebSockets, but everything looks very complicated.

To do this I did this so far:

HTML:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            //alert("Botao foi clicado");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax_move_camera/",
                data:{
                    "var1":"val1"
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                sucess: function(data){
                    alert("Sucess");
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("Error")
                }
            })  
        });
    });
</script>
```

VIEWS.py

```
def ajax_move_camera(request):
    x=10
    data={}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

URL.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.ajax_move_camera, name='ajax_move_camera')

]
```

Comment: Hey @Gustavo GeoDrones, you should change the url for `ajax_move_camera` to match up with the url you're using in your JQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

A rough draft on how you can approach this

**your_template.html**

```
<html>
    ... stuff ...
    <button id="camera_move_btn">Move Camera</button>
    ... stuff ...

<script>
    function call_this_function_on_btn_click() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_move_camera/",
            data: {
                "var1": "val1"
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken", "{{ csrf_token }}"
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                ... something comes back ...
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def ajax_move_camera(request):
    ... do something ...
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

you will have to match the ajax url to the view method in your `url.py` file and remember to include Jquery as I used their ajax method.

If you don't want to add Jquery you can look into [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) which will do the request.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but I tried this and it always getting a message error, also if I use "csrfmiddlewaretoken" the code does not work. Sounds like I'm missing something important here. I will update my question, so maybe you can see what's going on.